# If Statement (Do Nothing)

Tags: php, if-statement

this question is really about bad practice when it comes to PHP. I'm learning how to code in this language and I can already code in Lua & Python. When an if statement is told to "do nothing" in Lua, you would literally just say "return", but I understand that doesn't work in PHP. I've been using print() instead, but I understand that's probably bad practice and I was wondering if there was a function for doing nothing.

```
    if (condition) { //If condition is met
        print(""); //Do Nothing
    } else { 
        //Run the function;
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sure, just don't print or just exit.

Comment: you could just.. well.. do nothing? or: negate your condition and just use the code yurrently in your else-statement?

Comment: Flip it on its head, if the true is to do nothing remove it and look for the false `if( !condition ) {}`

Comment: this question's starting to look like "primarily opinion-based", IMHO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the easiest way would be:

```
if(condition) {

} else {
    // your code
}
```

the smart and clean way, however, would be to negate your condition:

```
if(!condition) {
    // your code
}
```

and be done with it.

**edit:**

if your condition is complex, don't forget to use parentheses:

```
if(!(condition_A && condition_B)) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: oh, and you could (and should) use the same principle for every other language. not just PHP.

Answer (score 1):

First off: You can use `return` in PHP, just as you do in Lua. However, when you use it in Lua it's within a custom function. If you copy this structure to PHP, and create functions for the different parts of the logic, then you will be able to (and should) use the `return` control statement to actually control application logic.

For your specific example, negating the condition may also help. Depending upon what it is you want to do. In the cases where you'd use the `return` statement, negating the condition won't be that helpful (only increase nesting).
That's why I leave you with two different methods to do this in PHP, depending upon what *else* you want the function to do:

**No more work in function:**

```
function doStuff ($param) {
    if ($param == null) {
        return;
    }
    // To stuff to the parameter.

    return $result;
}
```

**The function should do more:**

```
function doMoreStuff ($stuff, $limited = true) {
    $result = '';

    if (!$limited) {
        $result = 'More ';
    }

    return $result."stuff";
}
```

Granted these are pretty trivial examples, but they should give you a starting point to further improve your code and understanding of PHP. :)